# Homology functors defined on $\mathsf{Top} \times \mathsf{Top}$ in Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

The [Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+%28Eilenberg-Steenrod%29+cohomology) state that a homology theory is a sequence of functors $H_n : \mathsf{Top} \times \mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Ab}$ satisfying some additional properties.

What I don't understand is how a homology functor can be defined on $\mathsf{Top} \times \mathsf{Top}$? In the case of singular homology, we can define $H_n(X, A)$ in the case where $\iota: A \hookrightarrow X$ is a subspace by taking the homology of the cokernel of $S_n(\iota): S_n(A) \to S_n(X)$. How can we extend this to a functor on all of $\mathsf{Top} \times \mathsf{Top}$?

Edit: Looks like it was actually just a mistake on the nLab page.

Comment: The category of pairs is not $\text{Top} \times \text{Top}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think that is the reason for this question. I am also a little confused, because also almighty nLab seems to use the same notation, but somehow assuming that there necessarily exists an inclusion $U \hookrightarrow X$ for $(X,U)$, see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+(Eilenberg-Steenrod)+cohomology

Comment: And also it should be "The category of *topological* pairs is not Top $\times$ Top

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan that is what it says on the [nlab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+%28Eilenberg-Steenrod%29+cohomology), which is why I was wondering.

Comment: Why is this not a map of pairs? If $\text{conj}$ denotes the complex conjugate restricted to $S^1$ then $\bar{\iota} = \iota \circ \text{conj}$ so we have $\text{id}_{\mathbb{R}^2} \circ \iota = \iota = \iota \circ \text{conj} \circ \text{conj}= \bar{\iota} \circ \text{conj}$. Thus $\text{id}_{\mathbb{R}^2} \circ \iota: S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ factors through $\bar{\iota}: S^1  \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I deleted the incorrect comment (I misread your category). Your category is equivalent to the category of pairs $(X,A)$ where $A \subset X$ is a subspace, with morphisms $(X,A) \to (Y,B)$ given by continuous maps $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(A) \subset B$. Your category just adds an object isomorphic to $(X,A)$ for every automorphism of $A$, so it surely does no harm, though I don't really see what problem it solves, either. (I prefer thinking in terms of subspaces; perhaps you prefer thinking in terms of embeddings.)

Comment: I just prefer to think categorically, so embeddings are the more natural choice for me. Comparing underlying sets for equality to decide whether the domain of an embedding is in fact a subset (with the subspace topology) seems a bit [evil](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) to me.

Comment: The nLab is simply wrong, apparently... Since it's a wiki, anyone can fix it, though. By the way, you should look up [subobject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject), it's not an "evil" notion.

Comment: The nlab article should be edited.

Comment: @ Najib, yes the definition I wrote in my edit was for embedded subobjects rather than for subsets with the subspace topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there is an error in the nlab article so in fact the source category for the homology functors should not be $\mathsf{Top} \times \mathsf{Top}$. Instead, the source should be the subcategory whose objects are embeddings $\iota_A: A \hookrightarrow X$, and whose morphisms from $\iota_A: A \hookrightarrow X$ to $\iota_B: B \hookrightarrow Y$ should be continuous maps $f: X \to Y$ such that $f \circ \iota_A$ factors through $\iota_B: B \hookrightarrow Y$.

Equivalently, this can be describe as the category of pairs of spaces $(X, A)$ where $A$ is a subspace of $X$ and a morphism from $(X, A)$ to $(Y, B)$ is a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(A) \subseteq B$.